# Facebook comments change "like" button behavior?

Tags: comments, facebook-like

I've used like buttons on my site for several months using http://www.addthis.com/ and they've worked fine. Recently I decided to start using facebook comments on the pages instead of my previous commenting system but I've found that adding the plugin to the page has an unexpected impact on the "like" button.

The like button has been configured in the button_count style with no send button, however if the comments module is on the page the flyout appears upon liking the content. I don't want this to happen.

It may also be worth adding that there is a "like-box" on the page too but that it seems fine.

Does anybody know of a tie/conflict between comments and "like" buttons that would make this happen? Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the addthis plugin or iframe it, then use your javascript-sdk for the comments.  The sdk's are conflicting.